# How to get back from web view after some action is done there?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I am implementing the CCAvenue gate way in my application.
In which CCAvenue gateway is loaded in web view from my web site.

Now after Transaction is completed with Success/Failur page,How can i came to know and load my apps success page....
Please help me Friends

Comment: Show the attempts you've made at solving  this yourself.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `xcode IDE` so please don't use that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be for your web page to send a request with a custom scheme for example myapp://transactionSuccess and your app to handle this in the webView delegate:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSURL *URL = [request URL];
    if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"myapp"]) {
        // handle the response
        NSString *host = [URL host];
        if ([host isEqualToString:@"transactionSuccess"]) {
            // show your custom screen
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dan Spag is correct - URL Schemes make things a lot easier to manage and understand but sometimes these are just not possible. An alternative would be to ensure in the success / failure web page that in the dom (or HTML body response), the state of response is set and then capture that natively in iOS using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString like this...

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *responseState = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
 // or possibly a javascript property in the webview's loaded page if preferred.

   if([responseState isEqualToString:@"success"])
   {
       // do something with success
   } 
   else if([responseState isEqualToString:@"fail"]) {
      // do something with fail
   }

   [self.webView removeFromSuperView];

}
```